# images in carousel not fit

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4. There I have a carousel with picture. The images keep showing too big and like zoomed in. Idk what's the problem.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <img src="/images/holz_5.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h1>Lorem</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, minima.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <img src="/images/holz_6.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h1>Lorem</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, minima</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <img src="/images/holz_4.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            <h1>Lorem</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident, minima</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css code:

```
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
  position: relative;
  
}

.carousel-caption {
  bottom: 3rem;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-inner img {  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 32rem;
  object-fit: cover!important;
  display: block; 
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 32rem;
}
```

it looks like this:

it is too zoomed in.

[image: zoomed]

the original pic looks like this:
[image: normal]

Can someone pls help me to solve his problem?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is here:

```
 .carousel-inner img {  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 32rem;
  object-fit: cover!important;
  display: block; 
}
```

Try changing the object-fit and the height like that:

```
.carousel-inner img {  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain !important;
  display: block; 
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: now the image is very small in the middle of the carousel. is there any way to put images here? sry I am new to Stack!

Comment: What if you remove the height at all ?

Comment: I used my code but added this as you said:  ```object-fit: contain !important;```. But now the images are stretched. Hmm how to solve this now

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with your image so I can check it out ?